# BadRequestException in JAX-RS endpoint

Tags: java, curl, jax-rs

I have the following endpoint declared in my JAX-RS application:

```
@WebService
public interface AlertWeb
{
    @POST
    @Path("/add")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    public StringResponse addAlert(String name,
            int amount, String timespan, String repo, String action);

}
```

I'm using the following `curl` command to call this endpoint:

```
curl -X POST -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" 
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
-d "name=yellow&amount=2&timespan=DAY&repo=A&action=%7Baction%3A'GreenDivAction'%2C+message%3A'Simple+Message'%2C+args%3A+%5B'arg1'%2C'arg2'%5D%7D"
http://localhost:8080/AdminService/alert/add
```

but keep getting the following error when I make the request:

```
javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

**Note** Line breaks in curl syntax added for readability.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Works fine for me, after adding all the `@FormParam` annotations to the parameters

Comment: That's correct. I just discovered this after some additional googling. Please add as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: @peeskillet how did you get your environment set up that quickly btw? It always takes me a while to create new projects. Did you modify an old one?

Comment: I am actually working on a project right now. I use Jetty Maven plugin for development. Every change is picked, so no reloading. I just created your class and registered it. It was automatically picked up :-)

Comment: Also sometimes I'll use a maven archetype. That will get you up and running right away also

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll have to look into it for future projects.

Comment: Using `@WebService` on a JAX-RS endpoint will result in non-portable behavior.  It should be annotated `@Path`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add [`@FormParam`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/FormParam.html) to your method parameters if you want them to be injected as such

```
@POST
@Path("/add")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public Response addAlert(
        @FormParam("name") String name,
        @FormParam("amount") int amount, 
        @FormParam("timespan") String timespan, 
        @FormParam("repo") String repo, 
        @FormParam("action") String action) {
}
```